# django tutorial : http://localhost:8000/admin/

Tags: django-admin

I'm learning django framework, and I'm working on a remote server (alwaysdata.net).

I didn't find out what url should I put instead of `http://localhost:8000/admin/`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try **myaccount.alwaysdata.net**.

Comment: I didn't say it, but is pretty clear that myaccount.alwaysdata.net:8000/admin/ doesn't work :), even I have tried to run server with other port 8080, and it didn't work too.
I'm pretty sure that the problem comes from the server I'm using.